# Note manager like programmers IDE

Tags: ide, note-taking, hyperlink

This question follows "[Dead links in Onenote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/dead-links-in-onenote)".

It may be an unusuall question, but is there a note manager that has some features like programming IDEs? I use `OneNote 2013` but it has not some of my desired features. For example it may happen that same images exist in different pages and it is better to set that image in specific folder and set its link in pages. Also in onenote, we can create links to other pages/paragraphs. But there is no warning when you delete source of that link but in IDE, you can see error marks after deleting and you can undo that.

Comment: did you find a way to markup sources on OneNote? I.e. to have syntax highlighting for different programming languages in OneNote?

Comment: @Suncatcher No. I use MediaWiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then these are your requirements:

- A note manager keeping multiple notes
- Links between notes
- Notes can have images
- When a note/image is deleted, and some notice of this
- Running on Windows (extrapolated from the fact you are using OneNote 2013)

In my world, this translates into using a [personal wiki](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_wiki). They will give you all this, and help you organize your notes. Wikipedia also has a [list of wikis](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software), which might help you in your quest.

Personally I've used an ios based wiki engine called [Trunk Notes](//www.trunknotes.com/), but I'm contemplating on switching to something 'hosted' on my desktop instead of my iPad. My suggestion is to look into [Zim](//zim-wiki.org/index.html), [wikiDpad](//wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) or [Tomboy](//wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend: Markdown (markup language for notes/documentation) + Obsidian (knowledge base with local storage and graph navigation) and Typora (default MD editor), Google Drive with links for attachments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).